# Convert array into hash and add a counter value to the new hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following array of hashes:

```
[
  {"BREAD" => {:price => 1.50, :discount => true }},
  {"BREAD" => {:price => 1.50, :discount => true }},
  {"MARMITE"    => {:price => 1.60, :discount => false}}
]
```

And I would like to translate this array into a hash that includes the counts for each item:

Output:

```
 {
  "BREAD" => {:price => 1.50, :discount => true, :count => 2},
  "MARMITE"    => {:price => 1.60, :discount => false, :count => 1}
   }
```

I have tried two approaches to translate the array into a hash.

```
new_cart = cart.inject(:merge)

hash = Hash[cart.collect { |item| [item, ""] } ]
```

Both work but then I am stumped at how to capture and pass the count value.

Expected output

```
 {
  "BREAD" => {:price => 1.50, :discount => true, :count => 2},
  "MARMITE"    => {:price => 1.60, :discount => false, :count => 1}
   }
```

Comment: What if price/discount is different?

Comment: If it's different then that wouldn't be considered a duplicate entry.

Comment: Then what would the output be?

Comment: You can not create a hash with different values for the same key. It should be something like this: 
BREAD => [{price: 1, count: 2}, {price: 2, count: 1}]

Comment: @YuriMatusevich those are different hashes in the example.

Comment: @RevolverBloom having `"BREAD" => ...` looks nice, but it's kind of cumbersome when trying to process the data. Instead of creating nested single-key hashes, why don't you treat the name just like the other attributes, i.e. `{ name: "BREAD", price: 1.50, ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

We are given the array:

```
arr = [
  {"BREAD"   => {:price => 1.50, :discount => true }},
  {"BREAD"   => {:price => 1.50, :discount => true }},
  {"MARMITE" => {:price => 1.60, :discount => false}}
]
```

and make the assumption that each hash has a single key and if two hashes have the same (single) key, the value of that key is the same in both hashes.

The first step is create an empty hash to which will add key-value pairs:

```
h = {}
```

Now we loop through `arr` to build the hash `h`. I've added a `puts` statement to display intermediate values in the calculation.

```
arr.each do |g|
  k, v = g.first
  puts "k=#{k}, v=#{v}"
  if h.key?(k)
    h[k][:count] += 1
  else
    h[k] = v.merge({ :count => 1 })
  end
end
```

displays:

```
k=BREAD, v={:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}
k=BREAD, v={:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}
k=MARMITE, v={:price=>1.6, :discount=>false}
```

and returns:

```
  #=> [{"BREAD"  =>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}},
  #    {"BREAD"  =>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}},
  #    {"MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false}}]
```

`each` always returns its receiver (here `arr`), which is not what we want.

```
h #=> {"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true, :count=>2},
  #    "MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false, :count=>1}}
```

is the result we need. See [Hash#key?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) (aka, `has_key?`), [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

Now let's wrap this in a method.

```
def hashify(arr)
  h = {}
  arr.each do |g|
    k, v = g.first
    if h.key?(k)
      h[k][:count] += 1
    else
      h[k] = v.merge({ :count=>1 })
    end
  end
  h
end

hashify(arr)
  #=> {"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true, :count=>2},
  #    "MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false, :count=>1}}
```

Rubyists would often use the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to simplify.

```
def hashify(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    k, v = g.first
    if h.key?(k)
      h[k][:count] += 1
    else
      h[k] = v.merge({ :count => 1 })
    end
  end
end
```

Compare the two methods to identify their differences. See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object).

When, as here, the keys are symbols, Ruby allows you to use the shorthand `{ count: 1 }` for `{ :count=>1 }`. Moreover, she permits you to write `:count = 1` or `count: 1` without the braces when the hash is an argument. For example,

```
{}.merge('cat'=>'meow', dog:'woof', :pig=>'oink')
  #=> {"cat"=>"meow", :dog=>"woof", :pig=>"oink"}
```

It's probably more common to see the form `count: 1` when keys are symbols and for the braces to be omitted when a hash is an argument.

Here's a further refinement you might see. First create

```
h = arr.group_by { |h| h.keys.first }
  #=> {"BREAD"  =>[{"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}},
  #                {"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}}],
  #    "MARMITE"=>[{"MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false}}]}
```

See [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). Now convert the values (arrays) to their sizes:

```
counts = h.transform_values { |arr| arr.size }
  #=> {"BREAD"=>2, "MARMITE"=>1}
```

which can be written in abbreviated form:

```
counts = h.transform_values(&:size)
  #=> {"BREAD"=>2, "MARMITE"=>1}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). We can now write:

```
uniq_arr = arr.uniq
  #=> [{"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}}, 
  #=   {"MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false}}] 

uniq_arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  puts "g=#{g}"
  k,v = g.first
  puts "  k=#{k}, v=#{v}"
  h[k] = v.merge(counts: counts[k])
  puts "  h=#{h}"
end
```

which displays:

```
g={"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}}
  k=BREAD, v={:price=>1.5, :discount=>true}
  h={"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true, :counts=>2}}
g={"MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false}}
  k=MARMITE, v={:price=>1.6, :discount=>false}
  h={"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true, :counts=>2},
     "MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false, :counts=>1}}
```

and returns:

```
  #=> {"BREAD"=>{:price=>1.5, :discount=>true, :counts=>2},
  #    "MARMITE"=>{:price=>1.6, :discount=>false, :counts=>1}}
```

See [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Comment: The problem is that `{bread: {price:1.60, discount: false}}` should be considered uniq in comparison to `{bread: {price:1.50, discount: true}}` without a defined output

Comment: @engineersmnky, the question provides no guidance for what is required in the case you mention, so I concluded that was not being asked. Note the assumption I stated at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: However the comment from the OP states *"If it's different then that wouldn't be considered a duplicate entry."* in response to the question *"What if price/discount is different?"*

Comment: @engineersmnky, so we infer the OP would want `{ BREAD: { price:1.60, discount:false, count:1 }, BREAD: { price:1.60, discount:true, count:1}, MARMITE: { price:1.6, discount:false, count:1 } }`? A wee problem with that. Without a clarification I'll stick with my assumption and move on.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
arr = [
  { bread: { price: 1.50, discount: true } },
  { bread: { price: 1.50, discount: true } },
  { marmite: { price: 1.60, discount: false } }
]
```

Get the count for each occurrence of hash, add as key value pair and store:

```
h = arr.uniq.each { |x| x[x.first.first][:count] = arr.count(x) }
```

Then convert hashes into arrays, flatten to a single array then construct a hash:

```
Hash[*h.collect(&:to_a).flatten] 
#=> {:bread=>{:price=>1.50, :discount=>true, :count=>2}, :marmite=>{:price=>1.60, :discount=>false, :count=>1}}
```

Combined a couple of nice ideas from here:
  https://raycodingdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/array-of-hashes-into-single-hash-in-ruby/
and here:
  http://carol-nichols.com/2015/08/07/ruby-occurrence-couting/

Comment: You could speed this up by making a single pass through `arr` to obtain counts of all unique hashes (O(n)), rather than making a pass through `arr` for each unique element of `arr` to obtain the counts (O(n^2)). It should be noted that the calculation of `h` mutates `arr`. One generally assumes the given Ruby objects are not to be modified unless the question specifically calls for that.